# LSTM model loading producing weird results, non-serializable keyword arguments error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, load, deserialization, lstm

I am building an LSTM model with attention, it trains and tests well in the same session. I am getting problems saving, and loading the model in another session.

Problem 1) When I save the model with `model.save('my_model.h5')`, I get a weird warning:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py:872: UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword arguments: {'initial_state': [<tf.Tensor 's0:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'c0:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>]}. They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be missing at deserialization time).
  '. They will not be included '
```

Problem 2) Upon loading my model with `model = load_model('my_model.h5')`, at test time produces terribly inaccurate results.

I have tried saving the weights with `model.save_weights` and reloading them with `mode.load_weights`, but to no avail.

What is going on?

UPDATE:

```
def model(Tx, Ty, n_a, n_s, human_vocab_size, machine_vocab_size):

    X = Input(shape=(Tx, human_vocab_size))
    s0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='s0')
    c0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='c0')
    s = s0
    c = c0

    # Initialize empty list of outputs
    outputs = []

    ### START CODE HERE ###

    # Step 1: Define your pre-attention Bi-LSTM. Remember to use return_sequences=True. (≈ 1 line)
    a = Bidirectional(LSTM(n_a, return_sequences=True))(X)

    # Step 2: Iterate for Ty steps
    for t in range(Ty):

        # Step 2.A: Perform one step of the attention mechanism to get back the context vector at step t (≈ 1 line)
        context = one_step_attention(a, s)

        # Step 2.B: Apply the post-attention LSTM cell to the "context" vector.
        # Don't forget to pass: initial_state = [hidden state, cell state] (≈ 1 line)
        s, _, c = post_activation_LSTM_cell(context, initial_state = [s, c])

        # Step 2.C: Apply Dense layer to the hidden state output of the post-attention LSTM (≈ 1 line)
        out = output_layer(s)

        # Step 2.D: Append "out" to the "outputs" list (≈ 1 line)
        outputs.append(out)

    # Step 3: Create model instance taking three inputs and returning the list of outputs. (≈ 1 line)
    model = Model(inputs = [X, s0, c0], outputs = outputs)

    ### END CODE HERE ###

    return model
```

Comment: I think `initial_state` should not be passed to LSTM as a [parameter](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm). Can you remove it from your model?

Comment: I do not think I can. I am sorry I am a bit of a newbie at this. The LSTM model is created with the following code pasted above, the initial_state argument is crucial for receiving the state from the preceding layer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9914) on github describing this problem.

Here it was solved by describing the model that is saved differently. In this post they describe that it might be because you save a state, that is only known during training, but can not be reconstructed while loading. This is while it will not be stored and your problem 1. occures. And this one results in problem 2.